# Why don't Unity's window placement shortcuts work?

Tags: 11.10, unity, shortcut-keys

I am trying to use the Unity's Window Placement Shortcuts on Ubuntu 11.10 but they just don't seem to work. I even installed the package ccsm to ensure that the Grid option is enabled and the keyboard shortcuts are set the same as the standard Unity's shortcuts. The shortcuts are displayed in following list:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> - Place window in top left corner of screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 8</kbd> - Place window in top half of screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 9</kbd> - Place window in top right corner of screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> - Center/Maximize the window in the middle of the screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> - Place window in the bottom left corner of the screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 2</kbd> - Place window in the bottom half of the screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> - Place window in the bottom right corner of the screen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> - Minimize the current window.

What may be the cause for this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Are you actually using `Numpad 0-9` in those keyboard shortcuts?

> > ### This is a numpad
>
> [image: Picture of a numpad, with numbers in three rows and three columns on the keyboard]

The row of numbers of above the QWERTY keys will not work.

In future releases of Ubuntu (like 12.04) you will be able to tile windows using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd>.

Comment: Yes, I am using the numpad