# How do I enable the ALT + F10,F9 shortcuts?

Tags: shortcut-keys

Helo, why there is no ALT+F10 (maximize) or ALT+F9(minimize) shotcut in ubuntu 12.04?  Or can i enable them somewhere?

Comment: On the behalf of those who have to make a living using an IDE which grabs a _lot_ of keys:  Dear Canonical - please, only steal key combinations involving "Super" (the Windows key).  You are making the life of power users miserable.  If you MUST, then make it possible to undo these in the standard Settings dialogue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are on unity, then click the cog in the upper- right corner and choose `System Settings`

Now find the `Keyboard` entry, there you will be able to edit all your shortcuts.

You are looking for `Maximize window` and `Minimize window` they can be found under `Windows`. Just set the shortcut to whatever you want it to be.

[image]

Comment: In 13.04, Maximize window has been changed to Ctrl+Super+Up.

Answer (score 7):

There is already a bugreport:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/955965

this solution worked for me (comment #3)

> Unity design has decided to use Alt+F10 to show menus starting in Ubuntu 12.04. This >means you can no longer use Alt+F10 to maximize a window.
>
> WORKAROUND 1:
>   1. Run "ccsm" and go to General Options > Key Bindings.
>   2. Scroll down to "Maximize Window" (or "Toggle Window Maximized") and change the >keyboard shortcut.
>
> WORKAROUND 2 (should work, but doesn't seem to!?):
>   1. Run "ccsm" and go to Ubuntu Unity Plugin >Behaviour.
>   2. Disable "Key to open first panel menu" (Alt+F10).

Comment: Workaround 2 "Run "ccsm" and go to Ubuntu Unity Plugin >Behaviour. 2. Disable "Key to open first panel menu" (Alt+F10)." works for me in 14.04

Answer (score 4):

The default minimize key seems to be
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+numpad <kbd>0</kbd>

(see: [Why don't Unity's window placement shortcuts work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125247/why-dont-unitys-window-placement-shortcuts-work))

for maximize
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You can maximize windows by <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>̣↑</kbd> and minimize by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>̣↓</kbd>.

For more keyboard shortcuts hold down <kbd>Super</kbd> or take a look at `System Settings` → `Keyboard` → `Shortcuts` → `Windows`.

There you also can re-enable the old behaviour, but you have do disable the <kbd>F10</kbd> keybinding first, [which is described here](https://askubuntu.com/q/37313/46531).

Comment: i don't know, how to do the `.↑`  but changing the settings in the `System settings` > `Keyboard` > `Shortcuts` > `Windows` works for me, thanks

Comment: It is just the up-arrow.

Answer (score 2):

Just hold 2-3 sec. Super-Key and you will get a pop-up window with supported shortcuts

Answer (score -1):

Real working solution is in here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=129872 and then htop or mc works as before!