# How do I get keyboard shortcut working for maximise in gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> is supposed to be toggle maximise window but it doesn't function.

I've checked it is bound in ccsm > General > Key bindings and it is, but it's just not working. Ditto minimise.

Also the same is confirmed by Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts

Is there something else controlling/masking/blocking this?

(Nb. There are lots of posts on here about Unity; **I am not using Unity**, but Gnome Shell)

Comment: In Unity 12.04 Super+Up is for maximizing windows. Ctrl+Super+Down for minimizing. Possibly this works for Gnome Shell, too?

Comment: yep, you're right. how annoying. If you know a GUI/cli way to configure this behaviour pls do post an answer.

Comment: Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/q/131359/46531 - take a look at [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/131365/46531) there: before enabling Alt+F10 you possibly have to disable F10 behaviour (at least in Unity). I hope it works for Gnome Shell, also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In Unity 12.04 <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> is for maximizing windows." - Thanks to Jakob for this answer (in comments), this does work and so unless you *really* think it must be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, stick with this.

Comment: @jokerdino You can, but you have to wait 24hrs